# Show/movie with James Dean and time travel to prevent/ensure a car crash

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

Talking with my wife tonight and I said "Remember that show where someone went through time to set up James Dean's accident?". She doesn't remember it and I can't find it on simple Google or IMDB searches.

I cannot remember the overall plot. I remember an aerial scene of the car approaching an intersection and another car coming in and crashing into the first car. I have a vague feeling there may have been two time interventions, one to stop the crash and another to ensure it happened (but I am not sure).

I think it was most likely an episode in a series, but cannot promise it was not a movie. I watched it in the past 6 years (with my wife, though she does not remember it). No idea how old it was, but it was in colour, and I think not very old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it's not video at all — my mistake. "[The Cristobal Effect](https://www.lightspeedmagazine.com/fiction/the-cristobal-effect/?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=12477efc806954ae0b6a799a2dd0d080916c8067-1625289319-0-ATlJ1Ny5yyNu7lePiFu366afU-SlL-uVUgM7YP84HJEb_00PFRkdQMdwNwVt69XkCCvE7mrRoQPKD8ZMUsJUsrl7IhyrYJEa4iqW2OqDy3FUAg2za4oGQlWwQQCkydbsoWCJqvFgXDZ0z1Cr-q9rMambgw0i2LsHwj39FniIvKSxwiwErGXdNvhJSMPJgZ6i3wgqXwtGacek1tok9A8oOt0pREAuiGcsfRMyK9UgxWT-dMncwfbuQ3VwB-3K5PzW9kjD1IuFMDmDjTrHdzy9hsCZrLnYSXevQh9cIr_6SWV_KeAB0pMziSWoVQfGE8JcX0uGewDICuzDMoYRmJvX8NIy3Ad-p5-_1psgYhzmzx4iE1kTkw0dSuAumWzO2EFEZW0sM803ecFjTA9bvmd2gLjRXSXzHh3FogwJOqXgjwf8IC6bYZMkgseS3OWRaqPShQ)" by Simon McCaffery.

In the past few days I have been reading the anthology *Other Worlds Than These* edited by John Joseph Adams. I got it from the local library. By the second story, I knew I had read the collection before, but I didn't remember the stories well.

This morning I reached "The Cristobal Effect" and realised in the first couple of lines it was what I had been thinking of when I posted this question.

My memories of the story are so visual I am still surprised it was not something I watched, especially as I am generally more a reader than a viewer.

> We round a bend and cruise down a mild hill toward the 41 junction. A car is waiting, a ’50 Ford Tudor, idling on the centerline. Jimmy’s heart—my heart—begins hammering a slow drum-roll. Sweat rolls into my eyes. Piloted by the dependable Donald Turnipseed, the Ford hesitates and then lurches across the ash-colored highway. Rolf shouts above the wind as I veer directly into its path. His hand reaches for the wheel and I bat it away. No sense in fighting fate unless you’re in a Wobbly. The blunt chrome nose of the Ford blots out the high deep-blue sky. I glimpse its driver’s white face. It’s a good death, and just penance for my avarice.
>
> Jimmy’s face smiles in the mirror, young again. Immortal again. In that last instant before we hit, I give him a wink.